# Data base issue, site not displaying parent custom post types and additional errors

Tags: php, database, wordpress, post

I am posting here instead of the wordpress forum because I believe this is really a database issue that I cant figure out. I am running a wordpress site and I just tried to add a item to my custom menu and it doesnt save. I switched to the default theme (2012) and still nothing. I created a new menu, added 3 pages to it and saved....and poof they are all gone. I turned off all plugins and still the same thing.

So I started to look further. I went to upload my header image via the customize in the appearance area and it displays the good old "cheeting huh" text.

Then I added a plugin that I know adds an additional navigation tab in the dashboard navigation under "pages" tab and it wont show up. Also I am unable to access any posts. When I hover over "Posts" is only displays "categories" and "tags". Maybe its an issue with registering post types?

I had a notice at the top of my dashboard area that said I needed to upgrade to 3.5.1 and I thought awesome...ill just upgrade and all will be fine. But it didn't fix it.

I then deleted all wordpress files and replaced them with a fresh download and still no fix.

I searched google and found a possible solution of this:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );

to the wp-config.php file just before require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php')

define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);

to the wp-config.php file
```

No luck their either and my wp-config file looked totally normal.

I also checked my .htaccess file and it looks normal as well:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Finally I logged into my database and dropped all unused tables and optimized what was left but still nothing. This is on a working e-commerce website with over 100 products so it cant just be scrapped.

If I take some alternate routs to get to broken sections like the posts It still wont fork. For example if i go to the front end and go to a post and click edit, there is no button at the top of the page for "add new" like their should be. If I roll over the toolbar "+ new" it doesn't list posts. If I go directly to www.myblogname.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post it says "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." WHY...i can access everything else and my user role is admin.

So thats where I am now...any ideas? Is this a data base issue because I dont know whats left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow so you would never believe the answer.....USER PERMISSIONS. Some how my admin users permissions got messed up and it wasn't allowing it to show certain areas of the dashboard or to perform certain functions. I created a new admin user and BINGO. Everything was solved. Crazy.

So anyone with problems accessing areas of their Wordpress dashboard or performing particular functions, before you do anything, create a new admin user.